# Prove that if homogeneous linear system has at least two solutions, then it will have infinite amount of solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I would like to prove following proposition:

> Let $\mathbf u$ and $\bf v$ where $\mathbf u$ is not a multiple of $\bf v$  be solutions of a linear
>   homogeneous system $\bf Ax = O$. Prove that for any scalars such as k and c
>   the vector $k\mathbf {u} + c\mathbf{v}$ is also a solution of $\bf Ax = O$. In other
>   words,  $\bf Ax = O$ has an infinite number of solutions.

My attempt:

$$\tag1 \mathbf {Au = O } \implies k \bf Au = O  $$
Where k is scalar.

$$\tag2 \mathbf {Av = O } \implies c \bf Av = O  $$

Where $c$ is scalar.

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, we have

$$k\mathbf{Au} + c\mathbf{Av} = \bf O$$

Factoring out $\bf A$, we have:

$$\mathbf A(k\mathbf{u} + c\mathbf{v}) = \bf O$$

We've shown $(k\mathbf{u} + c\mathbf{v})$ is a valid solution, and hence we can conclude that linear system in question has infinite amount of solutions. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Well done!

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Well done!!

Comment: $0$ is a multiple of $v$ so $u\ne 0.$ So $ku=k'u \iff k=k'.$ Hence $\{ku: k\in \Bbb N\}$ is an infinite set of solutions

Comment: You could shorten the proof by starting directly with $\mathbf A(k\mathbf u+c\mathbf v)$ and using linearity of $\mathbf A$.